# Copy and paste custom objects from system clipboard

Tags: c#, multithreading, clipboard

I am using the bellow code for copy and paste the code via system clipboard from System.Windows namespace.

Copy code:

```
    var slide = new Slide { Name = "Developer", 
                 DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-30), Weight = 80 };
    IDataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
    dataObject.SetData("testcopy", slide, false);
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);
```

Paste code:

```
    IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    if (dataObject != null)
    {
        if (dataObject.GetDataPresent("testcopy"))
        {
            Slide slide = dataObject.GetData("testcopy") as Slide;
        }
    }
```

My Main function is [STAThread] attributed.

My problem is if I copy the object and close the application and open the same application(new process) and try to paste(read from clipboard), it is not returning the data (dataObject.GetDataPresent("testcopy") returning false).

Note: Slide class is marked as Serializable and I am able to copy and paste from the same thread in the same process.

Am I missing any implementation?

And when I try to remove [STAThread] attribute and try running via two differnt STA threads(copy one thread and paste another thread), the data copied in one thread is not present in the another thread.

Multiple thread creation:

```
           Thread staThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    actionToRun();
                });
            staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            staThread.Start();
```

Comment: Use some kind of serialization - either binary or string(fx. json) ... your example is working fine if I use `string` instead `Slide` even between processes...

Comment: Slide class is marked as Serializable and I am able to copy and paste from the same thread in the same process. So, it is not a serialization issue.

Comment: It is seriallization problem ... it cannot be serialized between process ... in other process you will prolly get `MemoryStream` so `as Slide` returns null ... remeber that Clipoard works in "COM universe" not ".NET universe" - it know nothing about .net serialization

Comment: @Selvin Should I try storing in MemoryStream and retrieve and then deserialize back?

Comment: Use json, as it's Clipoard works fine with strings ... remeber that you should not serialize UI objects ... you should serialize data(your model class) only - if it's somehow connected to the UI/framework classes/native objects then you should build own model and try to recreate this on the other side